# Accessing function from specific base class in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, derived-class, base-class

i have two functions with same name in two different classes. and both those classes are inherited into a third class. so in my third class i want to access the function of specific class. how do i do it..

```
class Base(object):
    def display(self):
        return "displaying from Base class"

class OtherBase(object):
    def display(self):
        return "displaying from Other Base class"

class Multi(Base, OtherBase):
    def exhibit(self):
       return self.display() # i want the display function of OtherBase
```

Comment: `class Multi(OtherBase, Base)` reverse the order of inheritance.

Comment: that works by changing the order. but what if i am accessing from outside the class. something like below
`minx = Multi()`

`print minx.exhibit()`

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Change the ordering of inheritance when defining `Multi`:

   ```
   Multi(OtherBase, Base)
   ```
2. Explicitly call the `display` method of that class:

   ```
   xxxxx.display(self)
   ```

For your particular use case, I would recommend the second. You can take advantage of default arguments and change your function's behaviour depending on how it is called.

```
class Multi(Base, OtherBase):
     def exhibit(self, other_base=False):
         if other_base:
             return OtherBase.display(self)

         return Base.display(self)
```

---

```
minx = Multi()

print minx.exhibit()
'displaying from Base class'

print minx.exhibit(other_base=True)
'displaying from Other Base class'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call it explicitly as `OtherBase.display(self)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the order of deriving the classes
as `class Multi(OtherBase, Base)`